# How to create a layout.js file in Next.js 13 if I use React Context providers?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, react-context, state-management

In Nextjs 13 there is a [reference](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide#migrating-_documentjs-and-_appjs/) to creating a layout.js file that replaces the app and document files, but they state that If you are using any React Context providers, they will need to be moved to a Client Component.
What does that mean exactly? The files should not be upgraded or you should mark 'use client' in the layout.js file?

Comment: **This is because Server Components have no React state (since they're not interactive), and context is primarily used for rerendering interactive components deep in the tree after some React state has been updated.** [Documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#context)